# Retrieve Exact Online data for which no Excel formula exists

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

I want to retrieve the outcome of the following query in an Excel cell:

```
select pro.code
from   ExactOnlineRest.Project.projects PRO
join   ExactOnlineRest.Manufacturing.shoporders SHO
on     SHO.project = PRO.ID
where  ShopOrderNumber = <value in cell F2>
```

The query works fine in the Query Tool. I can also use an Invantive Control block to retrieve the data as a list with one row/one column. But how do I retrieve the outcome of this query directly in an Excel cell without maintaining a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=I_SQL_SELECT_SCALAR("pro.code", "exactonlinerest..projects pro join exactonlinerest..shoporders sho on sho.project = pro.id", "shopordernumber = " & F2)
```

But please note that hard-coding SQL like this is error prone and be costly when upgrading since the SQL must be checked and possibly corrected by hand when fields change. Especially since this query uses a join and some SQL injection techniques which might be disabled on a future version.

You might want to make a list of needed frequently recurring manufacturing queries and have them added to the Excel formulas supported by Invantive Control.

It is also recommend to use an alias `pjt` for `projects`, using the style guide, and `sor` for `shoporders`.

Please also note that when the cell F2 is empty, the SQL will fail on the where clause. As an alternative you might want to add a "if empty then use 'null' or similar.